# Can one call a function from itself?

Tags: javascript

Can I do this:

```
function something(){

    for(x in y){
        if(x.toString() == "[object Object]"){
            something();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should use `typeof x === 'object'` instead of what you have there for your `if` comparison.

Comment: @Brad - I'm trying to check for just object literals, how do i do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It's called recursion, and it's available in JavaScript. In your case, it would be infinite recursion, which would cause a stack overflow. Make sure your condition for whether it's called or not will actually change to avoid infinite recursion.

Comment: In his case it wouldn't be an infinite recursion though cuz i guess `y` is a finite array after all !!

Comment: @UnLoCo, Yes, it would be infinite.  But, I'm sure the code posted is just an example, and not his actual code.

Comment: @UnLoCo Well, no, it won't be "infinite" .. the memory (and more so, the stack size/limit) is bounded .. it just will produce unexciting behavior ;-)

Comment: @pst okay bud i just commented based on the condition Jacob posted and that based on Brad saying "In your case" :)

Comment: @UnLoCo - Whether the `y` object is finite (which obviously it is) has nothing to do with the recursion. For the code shown if the `if` condition is true on the first call to `something()` it will be true for _every_ recursive call too, so that would produce "infinite" recursion up until it crashes with a stack overflow.